# How can i arrange columns in asp.net gridview?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

How can i arrange columns in asp.net gridview? i want to change 4 columns' location. ForExample:

column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |

ChangeOrder()

column2 | column1 | column3 | column4 |

ChangeOrder()

column4 | column2 | column3 | column1 |

---

I want to move columns in Gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options from the top of my head:

1. Turn AutoGenerateColumns off and add
   the columns yourself, mapping them
   to what you want in the dataset and
   in the order you want them.
2. Change your SQL query to return the
   columns in the order that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option for you, but the Telerik RadGrid supports this. See this [online demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/resizing/defaultcs.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

you can Remove column first and insert a new one at the remove index.
such as

```
var columnToMove = myGridView.Columns[1];
myGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
myGridView.Columns.Insert(0, columnToMove);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

1. Goto aspx page.
2. Click on smart-tag (>) of gridview.
3. Edit columns
4. Arrange column order in 'selected fields'

Hope it works..