# How to arrange the FieldName in AspxGridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I want to arrange the Field Names as user wants to display. I am not using SqlDataSource. I am calling the stored procedure by programming like below.

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQMatajerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetTotalSalesQuantity",con);
   cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", DateFromStr);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", DateToStr);
   //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", "2015-01-01 00:00:00");
   //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", "2015-12-31 23:59:59");

   con.Open();

   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   sda.Fill(ds);

   ASPxGridView1.DataSource = ds;
   ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
}
```

In result, I can see the field name how i have given the Column_name in my query. But, User wants to see the Field Name how they are arranging.

For Example:

```
select 
    student_id,student_name ,Class,School_Name
From
    Student_Details
```

If above one is my stored procedure. I will get the Field Name how I mentioned in my query.

But User wants to see the result how they are giving. If user give `School_Name,Class,Student_id,School_Name`.

Is there anyway to arrange in AspxGridView?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771688/how-can-i-arrange-columns-in-asp-net-gridview

Comment: @NagarajS The question is correct on that page. But my output expectation is not that one. I don't want to change my sql select statement and i don't want to create a column. Because, user may give different types of select statement on different time

Comment: you just want to change the header text or reorder the columns?should reordering be dynamic?

Comment: @shreesha I have 17 columns. I know that I can do drag and drop to move the columns. But it will take a time for each column. So before or after binding ` ASPxGridView1.DataBind();`, I want to arrange columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the hiddentext field and get the column names as user wants to display in which order.

   `string selectedColumns = HiddentxtSelectedColumn.Value;`
2. Move the `selectedColumns` to array

   ```
   string[] names = selectedColumns.Split(',');
   sda.Fill(ds);

   for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
   {
       ds.Tables[0].Columns[names[i]].SetOrdinal(i);`
   }

   ASPxGridView1.DataSource = ds;
   ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
   ```

Now It will run exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer Based on my understanding of the question and @mohamed's comment.

Try to use the [DataColumn.SetOrdinal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.setordinal(v=vs.110).aspx) method. For example:

```
con.Open();

   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   sda.Fill(ds);

   ds.Tables[0].Columns["School_Name"].SetOrdinal(0);
   ds.Tables[0].Columns["Class"].SetOrdinal(1); 
   ds.Tables[0].Columns["Student_id"].SetOrdinal(2);
   ds.Tables[0].Columns["School_Name"].SetOrdinal(3); 

   ASPxGridView1.DataSource = ds;
   ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
```

even if user changes the select statement order of columns will not change.

Comment: I am using DataSet not DataTable. Is it possible with DataSet like above?